# How to test for a connection in IBM MobileFirst V8

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

How can I check  in version 8 that I have a connection to MobileFirst server?.

I create a  cordova app in V8 using the MFP template and deploy it to my local instance  In the app.js file there is the function wlCommonInit(). How can I check in code for issue with the connecting to the server?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the obtainAccessToken API.

```
WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then(
        function (accessToken) {
          console.log(">> Success - Connected to MobileFirst Server");          
        },
        function (error) {
          console.log(">> Failed to connect to MobileFirst Server");  
          console.log(error);        
        }
);
```

Learn more:

- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/19/integrating-mobilefirst-foundation-8-in-ionic-based-apps/
- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/11/best-practices-for-building-angularjs-apps-with-mobilefirst-foundation-8.0/